# Binding two different ListItems in a List in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to bind two different ListItems in a list. One is StandardListItem and another one is DisplayListItem. I have a JSON Model which contains data. I have tried everything to bind data to these listitems but nothing is being displayed. Here is my code :

```
var oList = new sap.m.List("id_olist");
    var Sli = new sap.m.StandardListItem("id_sli",{
        title : "{myModel>/rootNode/name}"
    });
    var Sli1 = new sap.m.DisplayListItem("id_sli1",{
        label : "{myModel>/rootNode/srno}"
    });
    oList.addItem(oSli);
    oList.addItem(oSli1);
```

My JSON Model is :

```
var data = {
    "rootNode":[
            {"name":"abc","srno":"123"}
           ]
    };

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData(data);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"myModel");
```

Is it even possible? I need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things not logically correct / missing:

1. You haven't supplied a binding to your `sap.m.List` control, and
2. You are trying to display a list with two list items to the single same object `{"name":"abc","srno":"123"}` which isn't correct (it should be two separate objects in your model)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now for your first point, I tried setting the model to the list. It is not working. sap.ui.getCore().byId("id_olist").setModel(oModel,"myModel")

For the second point, do I need to create another model because I have tried with different rootNodes in a single model. It is not working.
Thanks

Comment: @ Qualiture ,  I tried the same example by creating two different models and binding each one of them to the different listitems. However, It is not working. I think that there is some issue in the binding statement. Will appreciate your help.

Comment: Apart from setting the model, you should also set the binding path, but since you are trying to create two list items from the same element in your array it probably won't work.... Just update your bindings to `{myModel>/rootNode/0/name}` and `{myModel>/rootNode/0/srno}` will work (effectively pointing to the first node in your array). Nevertheless, I would not do it this way but adapt your model to have one object for one list item.